# How to optimize long running cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have one query that is taking 10 minute and giving me 6852104 records. How can I optimize it? I have added execution plan as well.

[image: 2]

My query is like this:

```
    WITH CTE (columns name 
    )
    AS (
    SELECT  columns
    FROM #tempTable b  WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN physicaltable1 A ON A.ParentInvoiceItemId = b.InvoiceItemId
    INNER JOIN physicaltable2 c ON c.LinkedInvoiceItemId = a.LinkedInvoiceItemId
    AND c.HospitalId = B.Hospital_Id
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT columns
    FROM CTE LIP
    JOIN physicaltable1         LIC ON LIP.ChildInvoiceItemId = LIC.ParentInvoiceItemId
    INNER JOIN physicaltable12  LIH ON LIH.LinkedInvoiceItemId = LIC.LinkedInvoiceItemId
    AND LIH.HospitalId = LIP.HospitalId
    WHERE LIP.[Level] < 3
    )
    SELECT *
    INTO #newtemptable
    FROM CTE;
```

Comment: So your query is inserting 11,000 records per second. You find that slow?

Comment: yes because of this my sp is getting execute in 13 minute

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS, especially for performance-related questions. Despite the fact that it is possible to guess by query plan picture and syntax parts, it is not reliable and good way to look for help. [More info in SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2014 and 2019

Comment: Do you have any indexes on `#newtemptable` Also, please *tag* your question with the DBMS.

Comment: @AdilKhan . . . If you really want help, you should ask a *new* question.  Describe what you are trying to do.  Provide sample data and desired results.  Setting up a DB/SQL Fiddle of some sort would help (on a reduced data set!).  This question just doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Recursive CTEs on SQL Server tend to be bad performers when they're working on a lot of data (irrespective of index optimization). Rewriting your query to a script that avoids recursive CTEs could be a solution.